# DQS Task on SSIS is freezing at [DQS Cleansing] Information: The DQS Cleansing component sent 9637 records to the DQS server

Tags: ssis, data-cleaning

I'm trying to make some tests to verify a DQS SSIS task execution. When I run the task, a simple OLEDB source, a DQS Transform, and a OLEDB destination, the package freezes at this point. It is supossed to load up to 30000 rows, but the task on OLEDB is marked as completed and keeps running at the DQS Transform box.

I've checked on the client to see if maybe the process is created, but the Quality project isn't created and the DQS task is just frozen. Besides, previously when I made tests, the DQS transform used to take as few as 800 or up to 1000 rows, and now seems to be trying to take almost 10000 rows. I don't believe it's a matter of memory as the machine has 32 GB and it isn't a million records, just around 30000 rows.

I've tried to check logs and verify what might be going on, but I'm really stuck on here for almost two days without any idea on where else check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be that the issue came with an update for Microsoft Windows Sever. Reinstalled DQS Server, Uploaded the backup DQS file and it was running back again. Keep backups after every knowledge discovery, these are the only way to restore them after this issue.